# php guzzle [curl] 52 Empty reply from server

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2, guzzle, amazon-elb

I am making following request which resulted empty reply from server.

```
Originate server : AWS ec2 / PHP 5.4 / Guzzle 
Remote server : AWS ec2 through elb 
CURL info :{
  "url":"https:\/\/xxx\/xxx",
  "content_type":null,
  "http_code":0,
  "header_size":0,
  "request_size":5292,
  "filetime":-1,
  "ssl_verify_result":0,
  "redirect_count":0,
  "total_time":120.987057,
  "namelookup_time":0.000277,
  "connect_time":0.001504,
  "pretransfer_time":0.014271,
  "size_upload":2430,
  "size_download":0,
  "speed_download":0,
  "speed_upload":20,
  "download_content_length":-1,
  "upload_content_length":2430,
  "starttransfer_time":60.998147,
  "redirect_time":59.988895,
  "certinfo":[],
  "primary_ip":"54.169.126.111",
  "primary_port":443,
  "local_ip":"192.168.2.111",
  "local_port":39522,
  "redirect_url":""
} 

CURL error : [curl] 52: Empty reply from server [url] https:\/\/xxx\/xxx
```

Pls note that this does not happen all the time.

It seems like the request has not even reach the destination(elb) since there was no logs relate to the request 
1. Is the issue with originate server or remote server ? 
2. "starttransfer_time":60.998147 Could this be the root cause ?

Solutions,workarounds,suggestions are welcome.Thanks!

Comment: How often do you receive the failure? Is it possible to connect to all nodes behind the ELB individually to test connectivity? With the information you have provided, it sounds to me like intermittent network problems.

Comment: we receive around 6000 requests per minute and around 40-50 requests get failed.All these failed requests, transfer to a background process for retrying which eventually get successful.We do not notice any hikes on cpu or memory in both originate or remote clusters. No sign of 4XX / 5XX on elb access logs.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems request never reached the server,
Check for network errors. Any TCP re-transmission/timeout or any errors. As you mentioned no reply means is it TCP timeout? 
Run a tcpdump and analyse traces based on that you can decide.

Additionally you can enable log level in both applications in Originate and Remote servers.
Check for error patterns, ex: is it because of high load?

Answer (score 0):

In my case "empty answer from server" was caused by exhausted memory on the remote server. In this case fatal error was thrown and request was terminated.

Debugging cURL with `curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` did not help since there was only "Connection died, retrying a fresh connect" and then "Empty reply from server". We had to debug it on remote server's side.